# Codewars: The Hunger Games - Zoo Disaster

Tags: python

> **Notes** about the Problem: Animals can only eat things beside them.

> Animals always eat to their LEFT before eating to their RIGHT.
> **Always** the LEFTMOST animal capable of eating will eat before any others.
> Any other things you may find at the zoo (which are not listed above) do not eat anything and are not edible.

Can you help me?
Why I am getting: "Execution Timed Out"

KATA: https://www.codewars.com/kata/5902bc7aba39542b4a00003d/python

What can I do with IndexError?

My solutions:

```
animal_dict = {'antelope': 'grass',
               'big-fish': 'little-fish',
               'bug': 'leaves',
               'bear': ['big-fish', 'bug', 'chicken', 'cow', 'leaves', 'sheep'],
               'chicken': 'bug',
               'cow': 'grass',
               'fox': ['chicken', 'sheep'],
               'giraffe': 'leaves',
               'lion': ['antelope', 'cow'],
               'panda': 'leaves',
               'sheep': 'grass'}


def who_eats_who(zoo):
    if zoo == '':
        return ['', '']    #The condition calls for this
    process = []
    units = zoo.split(',') #from str to lst
    process.append(zoo)    #The condition calls for this
    try:
        while True:
            for i, k in enumerate(units):
                if k in animal_dict:
                    #check left eating 
                    if units[i - 1] in animal_dict[units[i]] and i != 0:
                        process.append(f'{units[i]} eats {units[i - 1]}')
                        del units[i - 1]
                        break
                     #check right eating

                    elif units[i + 1] in animal_dict[units[i]]:
                        process.append(f'{units[i]} eats {units[i + 1]}')
                        del units[i + 1]
                        break
                    else:
                        continue
    except IndexError:

        x = ','.join(units)
        process.append(x)
        return process
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `break` breaks from the `for` loop, not the `while` loop. This means you have an infinite loop.

Use this:

```py
        condition = True
        while condition:
            for i, k in enumerate(units):
                if k in animal_dict:
                    #check left eating 
                    if units[i - 1] in animal_dict[units[i]] and i != 0:
                        process.append(f'{units[i]} eats {units[i - 1]}')
                        del units[i - 1]
                        condition = False
                        break
                     #check right eating

                    elif units[i + 1] in animal_dict[units[i]]:
                        process.append(f'{units[i]} eats {units[i + 1]}')
                        del units[i + 1]
                        condition = False
                        break
                    else:
                        continue
```